# Como diminuir o tamanho dessa navigation bar?

Tags: xamarin, layout

Estou fazendo essa aplicação e precisei remover a seta de voltar, e após fazer essa remoção a barra continuou a existir, deixando a mesma muito grande e deselegante para a minha aplicação... Alguém sabe me dizer como fazer para diminui-la? Abaixo a imagem de como está:

Aqui a parte do código do mainpage:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class MainPageRoot : MasterDetailPage
    {
        private ListView menu;
        private ObservableCollection<MasterPageItem> _menuLista;

        public MainPageRoot ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            //menu = Master.navigationDrawerList;
            _menuLista = ItemService.GetMenuItens();
            navigationDrawerList.ItemsSource = _menuLista;
            Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(MainPage)));
           NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);


        }

        private void OnMenuItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var item = (MasterPageItem)e.SelectedItem;
            Type pagina = item.TargetType;

            Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(pagina));
            IsPresented = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Aqui o meu arquivo App.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());
    }

    protected override void OnStart ()
    {
        // Handle when your app starts
    }

    protected override void OnSleep ()
    {
        // Handle when your app sleeps
    }

    protected override void OnResume ()
    {
        // Handle when your app resumes
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Na verdade, provavelmente o que está acontecendo aí é que você tem uma MasterDetailPage dentro de uma NavigationPage. Compartilhe o código de criação da página e onde você define a MainPage do App para podermos ajudar.

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta inserindo o código!!

Comment: Nesse arquivo só tenho isso aqui <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="EbsHelpDesk.App">
 <Application.Resources>

  <!-- Application resource dictionary -->

 </Application.Resources>
</Application>

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza desculpe, foi sonseira minha... mas, editei dê uma olhada!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta tirar a NavigationPage que está encapsulando a sua MasterDetailPage.

Em algum lugar depois do login você deve estar fazendo algo parecido com isso:

```
// Dentro da página do login ou da view model de login você deve estar empilhando uma nova página na navigation do login.
this.Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPageRoot());
```

Altere esse código para algo assim:

```
App.Current.MainPage = new MainPageRoot();
```

Espero que funcione.

Comment: cara perfeito, isso mesmo... muito obrigado pela ajuda!